# Convert an integer to time format, so that you can calculated time differences with it

Tags: php, mysql

From my user table I retrieve an integer (e.g. 60) which is supposed to be the maximum of minutes that the user may use for his total break time.

When the user enters and exits his break, it's reorded in another table like this:

```
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_log (username, in_pause, action_time)
    VALUES ('$username', 1, '$timestamp')";
```

Where I write 1 for when he enters and 0 for when he exits.
I calculate how long the user's break lasted from those two recorded timestamps like this (after my sql query i put the timestamps into $zeiten[]):

```
    $pause_start = new DateTime($zeiten[1]);
    $pause_ende = new DateTime($zeiten[0]);
    $pause_diff = $pause_start->diff($pause_ende);
```

This works fine so far. But I can't seem to find a way to manipulate the integer (here 60) from my user table so that I can subtract my $pause_diff from it. I want to be able to calculate the break time that the user has left.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php

$max_minutes = (int) 60;
$zeiten[1] = '2000-01-01 10:00:00';
$zeiten[0] = '2000-01-01 10:10:00';

$pause_start = new DateTime($zeiten[1]);
$pause_ende = new DateTime($zeiten[0]);
$pause_diff = $pause_start->diff($pause_ende);
//$pause_diff->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$pause_diff_minutes =  $pause_diff->format('%i');

//var_dump((int) $pause_diff_minutes);

echo 'the differnece is: ' . ($max_minutes - (int) $pause_diff_minutes) . ' minutes';
```

The result is:

```
the differnece is: 50 minutes
```

[You can play with the code here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5298701d0d028e99e7b1768beea004a17ea35c8f)

Updated code showing how you could subtract also seconds from the 60 minutes:

```
<?php

$max_minutes = (int) 60;
$max_minutes_seconds = $max_minutes * 60; // max_minutes to seconds

$zeiten[1] = '2000-01-01 10:00:00';
$zeiten[0] = '2000-01-01 10:10:05';

$pause_start = new DateTime($zeiten[1]);
$pause_ende = new DateTime($zeiten[0]);
$pause_diff = $pause_start->diff($pause_ende);

$pause_diff_minutes =  $pause_diff->format('%i');
$pause_diff_seconds =  $pause_diff->format('%s');

// sum total diff in seconds
$total_pause_seconds = ((int) $pause_diff_minutes * 60) + $pause_diff_seconds;

$total_diff_seconds = ($max_minutes_seconds - $total_pause_seconds);

echo 'the differnece is: ' . $total_diff_seconds . ' seconds' . "\n";
echo 'which is: ' . floor($total_diff_seconds / 60) . ' minutes and ' . $total_diff_seconds % 60 .  ' seconds';
```

The result is:

```
the differnece is: 2995 seconds
which is: 49 minutes and 55 seconds
```

[play with it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8cee9abda014ac0b26f528ffe1c4deb092c1607)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I don't want to format my `$pause_diff` though, but i want to manipulate my number/integer 60, so that I can subtract my `$pause_diff` from that integer.

Comment: @nenfos updated the answer, not sure if that's what you are trying but hope it helps.

Comment: I want to re-open this. A good point was brought to me - users might want to know their break times accurately by seconds. As stated above I'm fetching the number 60 from my user table and i can not change that or the format of the number in that table, so i think i still need to prepare that integer after fetching it. I can put `$pause_diff`into the according format with minutes and seconds. But then, how do i substract that from my `$max_minutes` again? thanks

Comment: @nenfos There are a million ways to subtract seconds from minutes. For me the obvious one is to change the minutes to seconds, subtract it and then calculate the seconds back to minutes.. [try/play with it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8cee9abda014ac0b26f528ffe1c4deb092c1607) also updated answer with the code. I'm pretty sure you could have solved that by yourself. Don't just ask because it's easy, next time please try to do it yourself firstly. That will help you more in the long term.

Comment: thank you for your effort again. now that i see it, i could have done/found that. i actually did put in some hours of research before asking, i guess i just couldn't fit together the pieces. you are right though. thanks again!